# How to convert SWT events? Why does SWT notifyListeners method expects event type argument?

Tags: java, events, swt

Why does `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget#notifyListeners(int, Event)` method expects separate event type argument? Isn't it contained inside `Event` argument already? What if they do not coincide?

May I resend the same event with another id?

Suppose I wish to send `SWT.OpenDocument` in response to `SWT.MouseDoubleClick`

```
public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    if (event.type == SWT.MouseDoubleClick) {

        notifyListeners(SWT.OpenDocument, event);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source of `Widget#notifyListeners(int, Event)` and follow the method calls to [`Widget#sendEvent(int, Event, boolean)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.6/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux/x86_64/3.6.0/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Widget.java#Widget.sendEvent%28int%2Corg.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event%2Cboolean%29) You can see the following:

```
void sendEvent (int eventType, Event event, boolean send) {
    if (eventTable == null && !display.filters (eventType)) {
        return;
    }
    if (event == null) event = new Event ();
    event.type = eventType;
    event.display = display;
    event.widget = this;
    if (event.time == 0) {
        event.time = display.getLastEventTime ();
    }
    if (send) {
        sendEvent (event);
    } else {
        display.postEvent (event);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `Event` is "filled" for you, so it's impossible to have interfering/contradictory event types.

The event you specify in the method call of `notifyListeners` will be used in any case.